# Pandas KeyError When Merging

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm new to Pandas and i'm trying to do a left join between two Data Frames. I'm getting a KeyError. Could someone spot my mistake? I'd imagine it's probably something easy that i'm missing. Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd


remediation_file = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\garyd\\Desktop\\remediation-workbook.xlsx')

exception_file = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\garyd\\Desktop\\exception-finished-file.xlsx')


remediation_file['Concat ID-Resource'] = remediation_file['ID'] + remediation_file['Resource'] 

exception_file['Concat ID-Resource'] = exception_file['ID'] + exception_file['Resource'] 

indexed_remediation_file = remediation_file.set_index(['Concat ID-Resource'])

indexed_exception_file = exception_file.set_index(['Concat ID-Resource'])

# print(indexed_remediation_file)

# print(indexed_exception_file)


join_file = pd.merge(indexed_remediation_file, indexed_exception_file, on = 'Concat ID-Resource', how='left')

# print(join_file)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines

```
indexed_remediation_file = remediation_file.set_index(['Concat ID-Resource'])

indexed_exception_file = exception_file.set_index(['Concat ID-Resource'])
```

make the joint column an index of each of the DataFrames. Therefore, when you want to merge, instead of using

```
on='Concat ID-Resource'
```

use

```
left_index=True,
right_index=True
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped out a bunch. Now I just have to remove the extra columns that I don't need.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to merge two dataframes by *indices* use [df1.join(df2)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

if you want to merge 3+ DFs by indices use: [pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)

Comment: Ugh, I always specified `left_index` and stuff; turns out it's the default LOL.

Comment: @AmiTavory, yeah, it makes the code a bit shorter ;-)